# Eclipse on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, plugins

i installed eclipse/galileo on mac x 10.5.
i'm trying to install subversion plugin, but the eclipse help menu is actually mac's help menu, so i cannot get to the software update menu item.

How do i install a plugin on mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the bottom of the help menu, you will find the submenu for eclipse software updates.

Comment: there is a menu check for updates (which checks for updates) and install new software (which allow to add sites for installation). But where to find which are the current installed plugins.

Comment: @kaychaks, in the Software Updates menu item, there are two options: 'Find and Install...' and 'Manage Configurations.'  select the manage configuration option and it will popup a dialog that will give you the information you need.  (i am using 3.3.1.1)